# ActiveMQ: Unable to delete scheduled message

Tags: node.js, activemq-classic

I'm having some trouble when trying to delete a scheduled message. I'm using nodejs with stompit. Below is my function which is supposed to delete **all** messages from the queue. I've set the headers according to the documentation. The response from ActiveMQ is "Message sent", yet I don't see the message removed.

```
/** @method     remove
 * Removes a JOB from our ActiveMQ instance
 * @param      {object}   text JSON object containing the details of the ticket to be created
 * @param      {string}   topic Topic to send message to.
 * @param      {boolean}   redelivered Mark if message has been redelivered.
 * @return     {Promises}  On resolve it returns a response, on reject it returns an error.
 */
remove: function(text, schedulerOptions) {
    var servers = [server1, server2];
    var headers = {
          'destination': 'AMQ_SCHEDULER_MANAGEMENT_DESTINATION',
          'content-type': 'application/json', 
          'persistent': sails.config.activemq.environments[thisEnv].persistent,
          'AMQ_SCHEDULER_ACTION' : 'AMQ_SCHEDULER_ACTION_REMOVEALL',

    };
    pri.sendMessage(servers[index], headers).then(function(response){
        sails.log.debug("Message sent!");
        sails.log.debug(response);
        return resolve("Message Sent");
    }, function(error){
        //retry with the second activemq IP
        index = 1;
        pri.sendMessage(servers[index], headers).then(function(response){
            return resolve("Message Sent");
        }, function(error){
            rejection.message +='Error Connecting to Queue';
            return reject(rejection);
        });
    });
  });
```

The thing is that nothing happens. I have also tried removing a specific message with a specific jobid, that didn't work either.

If someone could please point me to what am I doing wrong, I will highly appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: How do you know nothing happens?  What your test criteria?

Comment: Hello Tim. Thank you for responding. I login to the ActiveMQ Console, and go to the Scheduled tab, I still see the entry of a test job I've entered previously there even though I execute remove all.